# Can I use "pure" Greek letters in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

By pure Greek letters I meant

```
\int_γ f(ζ)\,dζ
```

instead of

```
\int_\gamma f(\zeta)\,d\zeta
```

Visually they are almost identical. Is this acceptable within the current system?